# L4 Custom validators: Array must have only one primary

Tags: php, json, validation, laravel-4

I am building an API which -not surprisingly!- accepts JSON.

A certain element of the passed JSON, let's call it "games" is an array and accept one or two elements, with the following structure (this one must fail):

```
"games": [{
        "title": "Blabla",
        "primary": 1
    },
{
        "title": "Blabla2",
        "primary": 1
    }
]
```

So, my aim is to build a custom validator which allows only one of the games to be primary.
I have started building something like this, but I am not quite there:

```
Validator::extend( 'primary_unique', function ($gamesRules, $gamesArray, $parameters, $validator) {


        if (count($gamesArray) > 1) {
            $primaryExists = false;
            foreach ($gamesArray as $game) {
                if ($primaryExists && $game['primary'] == 1){
                    return false;
                }
                    if ($game['primary'] == 1) {
                    $primaryExists = true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Please consider that I am using Laravel 4.2 for this project.

As an example, this one should pass the validation:

```
"games": [{
        "title": "Blabla",
        "primary": 0
    },
{
        "title": "Blabla2",
        "primary": 1
    }
]
```

Any ideas are more than welcome!

Comment: What is this variable `$gamesValue` that you're looping?

Comment: That should be `$gamesArray`; fixed in the description.

Comment: This seems to be working when I test it. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, the last code snippet is valid so it  is working, but what about the very first that should fail?

Comment: The first one returns *false*, everything about your logic is great.

Comment: Ah, I just realised that I was validating the array elements one by one, instead of the entire array. :)